# Why always pass context to adapter in android?

Tags: android, adapter

There is view, there is context.
I can get context in getView() method as below.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(null!=context){
            context=convertView.getContext();
        }
    }
```

Why r we always pass context to adapter? I never thought about that before.

Answer (score 0):

`convertView` passed to `getView()` can be null in case there's no view being recycled. Calling `getContext()` on a `null` will NPE.

`Context` is Android UI code is available everywhere and is easy to pass in as an explicit constructor argument. Doing so helps keep your code more understandable by others or future you.